# Multiple Lua environments issue

Tags: c++, c, lua, luabind

I'm having trouble on creating multiple Lua environments to run multiple similar scripts in the same lua_State.
The program crashes with the following error

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)
```

Here's the Script.Compile and Script.runFunc methods:

```
void Script::Compile() {
    if (m_filename.IsEmpty()) return;

    if (m_filename.Contains("res:")) {
        astd::String file = m_filename.Replace("res:", "");
        astd::String filecontent = AEIO::OpenTextFromAssetPack(file);
        m_lua->RunString(filecontent);          
    } else {
        m_lua->RunScript(m_filename);
    }
    astd::String id = astd::String("file") + astd::String(UID);
    lua_setfield(m_lua->State(), LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, id.CStr());

    UID++;
}

void Script::runFunc(astd::String func) {
    astd::String id = astd::String("file") + astd::String(UID);
    lua_State* state = m_lua->State();

    // Weird behaviour during debug.
    // The debugger goes back and forth on these 2 lines.
    lua_getfield(state, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, id.CStr()); 
    lua_getfield(state, -1, func.CStr()); // CRASH!

    if (lua_isfunction(state, -1)) {
        lua_pcall(state, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    luabind::globals(state)["self"] = m_owner;
}
```

And this is the basic structure of the scripts:

```
print("Script Created") --Gets printed before the error occurs.

function onInit()
    print("Script Initialized")
end

function onUpdate()
    print("Script Update")
end
```

And it only fails when I call `runFunc("onInit")` or `runFunc("onUpdate")`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) you almost surely need to show more code than this, like an MWE, to really know. (2) if I were you I would try inserting debugging output between those two lines, and inspect the output of `lua_istable(state, -1)`. If the top is not a table, that is the simplest reason that `lua_getfield(state, -1, func.CStr());` would crash.

Comment: Yeah, `lua_istable(state, -1)` returns false. I dont understand, because this code used to work before :S
What do you mean "show more code than this, like an MWE" ?

Comment: (1) "MWE" is "minimal working example", something that i can actually copy off of the question, paste into a text file, and compile to reproduce the problem. (2) if `lua_istable(state, -1)` is returning false, then that's definitely a showstopper :S good luck

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question. Your answer should be posted below as an answer.